# WebClient: How to handle an error which has 200 status but body has an error messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

I'm connecting the API using Spring WebClient and the API sometimes returns some errors with status 200.
I know how to handle errors when the status is different than 2xx, but I'm stuck to handle this case.

```
200 OK
{"error":"token_not_found","error_description":"Token Not Found"}
```

One way that came to my mind would be to parse the body to custom error class and check if it has an error message otherwise parse it to Pojo class.

What is the best way to handle this kind of cases?

**Update**

Here's my solution:

Added `error` and `error_description` fields on POJO class.

```
class Customer {
   private Long id;
   private String email;
   ...
   private String error;
   private String errorDescription;
}
```

Webclient:

```
webclient
.exchangeMono(response -> response.bodyToMono(Customer.class))
.doOnNext(o -> {
  if (o.error() != null) {
    // do smth with error
    throw new RuntimeException(o.error());
  }
})
```

Comment: It is not uncommon and I don't think you have any choices here... you need to parse the response. If you are mapping the response to a POJO, you might just need to catch exception on the parsing error but you'd have more control checking it first